# How to - Build Custom drupal 8 module form

Tags: drupal-8, drupal-modules

I am new to `Drupal 8` and came to know that Drupal 7 is going to end at 2021. Currently, trying to build a module in Drupal 8 which displays a form.

When submitting this form value should be stored in a database.

Can anyone please guide me

Answer (score 0):

The first way, you can install the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) contributed module. You can enable some sample children module in this module to know how to the webform store data.

The second way, you can install the [Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) contributed module and enable form_api_example (in the Examples module). This module will show you how to create a custom form, simple form, ajax form, modal form, multistep form, etc.

I hope with 2 contributed modules, you can know how to build your custom form.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link which shows how to create a custom form within a module.
https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/step-by-step-method-to-create-a-custom-form-in-drupal-8
You can save the value into a database by creating a custom content type for the form and using $node->save(); in submit function of the form.